# When to fetch data and when to update state?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I don't know if there is a best practice that is accepted for this. I have a component which fetches data inside `useEffect` using axios and updates the state (`setData`) based on the response. Response returns an array of objects, i.e:

```
[
  {"title" : "Foo", "value":1},
  {"title" : "Bar", "value": 2}
]
```

User is allowed to delete an item from the list. When user deletes an item, I send a `DELETE` request using axios, but I also update the state like this:

```
setData(data.filter(d => d.id !== item.id))
```

which re-renders the component and the item is gone. I wonder whether this shouldn't be done by updating the state but rather using `useEffect` to fetch the data, and waiting for backend to send the response.

Is there a best way performance-wise?

Comment: Can you show some relevant code, so that we can see what's going on

Comment: I fetch data using axios inside `useEffect` and set the data. Nothing to see really pretty common concept

Comment: If you using state to store data, you can use it normally, call Axios to update data. Personally, I advise you should using state management + redux middleware to handle async process.

Comment: The reason I am not providing code is I have a redux middleware and need to do a codesandbox which I don't have time to. My fetchData function uses redux & redux-thunk, and I get the data from redux store. However, when the user deletes an item from the list, I don't know if I should use redux to update the component, or just fetch the data from backend as it is also deleted there

Comment: You may consider using an external server state library like React Query, or SWR. They will do the heavy lifting for fetching and caching, and allow you to invalidate queries after mutations (so data refetching will be automatic). A wise pattern would be to use Redux for UI state only, and a dedicated tool for server state. See https://react-query.tanstack.com/overview for instance.

Comment: Thanks @FlorianMotteau I will check out those libraries for sure. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem here is **what happens on server's error**.

Therefore having a middleware or updating the state on success will ensure the component have the most updated data.

```
// No middleware
axios.delete(url).then(() => setState(...));

// Middleware
axios.delete(url).then(() => updateStore(...));
// ... Component listening to store updates
```

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't duplicate the state (in this case you handle the state twice - one which you fetch and one in the component), so I highly recommend not use this pattern although it gives a little faster UI feedback (use it when you are optimistic and server is slow).

```
// optimistic
setData(data.filter(d => d.id !== item.id))
axios.delete(url).catch(() => setState(prevStateBeforeError));
```

Comment: Yes thunk is a middleware too

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you are only updating the state based on the success response of delete request. But as a best practice, after creating request, instead of updating the state, you should call the fetch API to ensure you have the updated data all the time, by which you will also handle the error case if the request fails.

Comment: I get the approach, but what do you mean by "after creating request, you should call the fetch API" ? Is it fetching from API in  `useEffect` and making sure after deleting the node component re-renders?

Comment: Yes, same fetch API which is written in useEffect, which when yields any response then the list component will re-render.